# Why the map command has something to do with sequence?

Tags: firefox, vim

The vim installed on my win7. A map command has been added in the configuration file `_vimrc`.

```
 nnoremap <F12> :exe '!"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" %' <CR>
```

Sequence1:
1.to select gvim  and open it.
2.to open the target html file in gvim
The file name is test_audio.html in the example.
3.to press F12
The firefox will be called and `file:///C:/test_audio.html` will be displayed in the firefox browser window.

Now my target file will be opened by chrome,it is ok.

Sequence2:
1.to select the target html file and open it with gvim.
The file name is test_audio.html in the example.
2.to press F12
The firefox will be called and `test_audio.html` will be displayed in the firefox browser window.

Now my target file will not be opened by chrome,failed.
Why?How to fix the problem in sequence2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that you need to pass the complete path with not just `%`, but `%:p`

BTW, there is a function in netrw standard plugin to open files into the browser. It would have used something like

```
nnoremap <F12> :call netrw#NetrwBrowseX(expand('%:p'), 0)<cr>
```

Comment: nnoremap <F12> :exe '!"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" %:p' <CR>

Comment: It works on your current machine with your current browser. `netrw#NetrwBrowseX()` will try to detect the right browser depending on the OS, and on the default browser registered to windows, in windows case. In other words, it's a portable mapping.